# 404 not found when accessing JSON WCF Service with jQuery

Tags: wcf, json, jquery

I have a WCF service hosted in IIS which seems to be running fine but am unable to access it through jQuery on the client side.

My site structure is like this -

```
localhost:9080/Website 
localhost:9080/WCFService
```

I've set the anonymous authentication user id to that of the AppPool identity.

When I try to access a GET method from the browser, it returns the JSON data just fine. But when I try to access the same method from the client using jQuery $.ajax() the server returns a 404 error.

The URL of the WCF method is

```
localhost:9080/WCFService/Service.svc/SimpleMethod
```

The signature of the method is

```
string SimpleMethod()
```

I've already tried looking articles online and I don't think the `web.config` is any different. It looks like a permissions thing to me.

Can anyone shed any light on this issue?

-Thanks!

Comment: If you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( { } ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what I did -

Added an endpoint behavior which uses `<webHttp />` and removed `<enableWebScript />`. That fixed it.

Comment: Can you please elaborate?  I'm having the same problem.

Comment: @abjbhat can you explaine to me how can I do this?

Comment: Yeah, in your web.config, look for enableWebScript.. remove it and add webHttp

Answer (score 0):

> When I try to access a GET method from
>   the browser, it returns the JSON data
>   just fine

You are accessing from the server pc and using http://localhost:9080

> But when I try to access the same
>   method from the client using jQuery
>   $.ajax() the server returns a 404
>   error.

- What URL are you using for ajax call? Use relative URL.

> It looks like a permissions thing to
>   me.

If on same machine (server machine) invoking directly from browser works but invoking using ajax from same client does not work, it can be a wrong url

You better post your ajax calling code.

Comment: I thought about that too, but the URls were fine.